# Improve image quality using Emgu.CV

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I am trying to read text from images using Tesseract. As the image quality is not good I'm using image processing before tesseract-ocr to improve the accuracy.

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaA8M.jpg

Wrote below code to detect edges by using a Gaussian filter:

```
var img = new Image<Gray, Byte>("ZaA8M.jpg");
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Source_Gray = img.Copy();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Egde_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.CopyBlank();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_SourceSmoothed_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.CopyBlank();
Image<Gray, byte> Img_Otsu_Gray = img.CopyBlank();

//Smooth the edges by using a Gaussian filter
Img_SourceSmoothed_Gray = Img_Source_Gray.SmoothGaussian(3);

//Segmentation of the characters by using a threshold
CvInvoke.Threshold(Img_Source_Gray, Img_Otsu_Gray, 255, 0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Otsu | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);

Bitmap imgb = (Bitmap)byteArrayToImage(Img_Otsu_Gray.ToJpegData());
imgb.Save("test.jpg");
```

Output image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj8XX.jpg

After applying the threshold, characters become more dark black color and not it's readable.

How to improve the above image quality to read the text from it using tesseract-ocr?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing to much image processing. For example your original image already has letters that are touching each other. By applying a SmoothGaussian filter, you are likely making those edges blend even more into each other, although you are smoothing out some irregularities at other spots.
Also I prefer working with png images instead of jpg when the input is low quality, because the jpg compression adds another layer of quality loss.

I did a single filter on your image with well chosen parameters (vb.net)

```
img.ThresholdAdaptive(New Gray(255), CvEnum.AdaptiveThresholdType.GaussianC, CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary, 45, New Gray(9))
```

and this is my image result

[image after adaptive filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJeM4.png)

here is my Tesseract result

```
Supplement Facts
Serving Size 30 Drops (1 ml)
Servings Per Container 30

Amount Per Serving 333mg
Herb Weight Equivalence

Organic
Milk Thistle Seed
(Silybum marianum)

Herb Strength Ratio 1:3

* Daily Value Not Established

OTHER INGREDIENTS: :
ionized Water, Grain Alcohol
(20-30% by volume) |

— 4
```

using this as tesseract v5.0.0 command line

```
tesseract.exe --oem 3 --psm 3 -l eng "c:\temp\input.png" "C:\temp\output"
```